# How to check dropped text position inside a textbox?

Tags: javascript, xul, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a textbox with string, and want to check that user dropped text between textbox string or at end of textbox string. Is there is any Javascript function to do this task? I tried `createTextRange()` and `setSelectionRange()` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myTextInput" value="test" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JS**

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myTextInput');
var defaultValue = myInput.value;

myInput.addEventListener("input", function () { 

    var index = myInput.value.indexOf(defaultValue, 0);
    if(index == 0)
        alert('The text has been added at the end of the original string');
    else if(index == -1)
        alert('The text has been added inside the original string');
    else
        alert('The text has been added in the front of the original string');

}, false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CdryJ/1/)
​